# How to find a link element with an specific url inside DOM via webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I'm using [webdriver io](http://webdriver.io/) for testing a web page.
I need to check if one element with an specific href exist on the page.

I have made I try with this

code

```
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

     .elements('.mylinkclass', function(err,res) {
        res.value.forEach(function(elem){
                client.getText(elem).then(function(text) {
                if (text=="www.superweb.com"){
                   console.log("allright!");
                }
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will find an element by the CSS selector 'a' and then get its text. This means it will get an arbitrary element with the HTML tag 'a'. To fix that specify the value of the 'href' attribute in the CSS selector:

```
client
.element("a[href='http://www.superweb.com']") // will only select a elements with the specified href attribute
.then(function(elem){
    console.log(elem); //found!
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("err", err); //will be executed if no elements containing your URL are present
});
```

You also might want to check out the link text selector:

```
<a href="http://www.superweb.com">www.superweb.com</a>

client.getText('=www.superweb.com', function(err, text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

source: http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html

Comment: Yes you're right but I think this code doesn't work for what I'm expecting; I need to find the way to compare all the links in the DOM in order to check if one of them contains the url that I'm looking for.

Comment: The 'a[href='http://www.superweb']' selector will do that unless I misunderstood you. If it doesn't work add example html to the question and I will edit my answer.

Comment: I've edited the question; its very simple imagine you wanna find some link in a webpage that has many paginated results, since you don't fine the url your search for you will need to paginate. That's what I'm trying to do, I put a piece of code(not all) but my intent is that, paginate over results since I don't find the link I'm looking for.

Comment: hey, check the edited answer. I added the link text selector example.